# when keyboard is open layout should move above in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to move my layout above when keyboard is on. I have tried  with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`. But this is not working.
When I click on `EditText` it should move above so that the TextView should be visible.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EnterPin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/top_bar"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_home_change_pin"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_btn_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#417883"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_company_name_check_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="BURBLE ME"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Thank you for claiming your account"
        android:textColor="#5DA5AE"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Now please enter a PIN.You will use this to allow other Burble enables Dropzones to import you."
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="18dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_current_pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter Pin"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_confirm_pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_shape"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Confirm Pin"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pin_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:shadowDx="1.5"
            android:shadowDy="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="Back"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_change_pin"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
            android:shadowDx="1.5"
            android:shadowDy="2"
            android:shadowRadius="2"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="What will I use this for?"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="You will use your PIN at your dropzone to manifest using their equipment and to allow a new dropzone to add you to their Burble system."
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this line of code in manifest activity declaration.
  <activity
            android:name=".ACTIVITY NAME"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your layout .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_home_change_pin"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="#417883"
            android:textSize="11sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_company_name_check_in"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="BURBLE ME"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Thank you for claiming your account"
                android:textColor="#5DA5AE"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                android:text="Now please enter a PIN.You will use this to allow other Burble enables Dropzones to import you."
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="18dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_current_pin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="Enter Pin"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" >
                </EditText>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_confirm_pin"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:hint="Confirm Pin"
                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="14sp" >
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:weightSum="2" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_pin_back"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1.5"
                    android:shadowDy="2"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:text="Back"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_change_pin"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
                    android:shadowDx="1.5"
                    android:shadowDy="2"
                    android:shadowRadius="2"
                    android:text="Next"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="What will I use this for?"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="You will use your PIN at your dropzone to manifest using their equipment and to allow a new dropzone to add you to their Burble system."
                    android:textSize="12dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line below to the activity this layout is inflated in. (AndroidManifest.xml) `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan"`